# Animate and Expand div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

Here's my problem: I want to hide content behind a button, then when the button is pushed I want the content wrapper to expand horizontally and vertically to reveal the hidden content. I have figured out how to animate the div vertically, but horizontally am having problems. I want the content wrapper to expand from 300px wide at start to 900 px wide later.

The javascript holder is assigned to panel

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-slide").click(function(){
 $('#panel').animate({
opacity: 0.25,
height: 'toggle',
}, 1000, function() {
// Animation complete.
});});   
});
```

I want the wrapper width to expand from 300px to 900px. Currently, the wrapper expands vertically properly, but the width does not. The wrapper css is set to:

```
#wrapper {
width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 40px;
background-color:#FFF;
border-radius: 42px;
-moz-border-radius:42px;
padding:30px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `width: 900` to the animation property list.

Comment: SLaks: thanks, but adding width: 900 under height:'toggle' did not solve my problem

Comment: Perhaps I need to attach width: 900 to the wrapper div? If so, how do I add the proper syntax?

Comment: You'd need a separate call to `animate` on that element with just one property.

Comment: Thanks SLaks. I have it working properly on click now. Just one last snag before completely solving my issue: How do I reverse the animation when the button is clicked a second time?

Comment: Animate to `1200 - $('#wrapper').stop(true, true).width()`.  The `stop` call stops any current animation so you don't see an in-between width.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand div you could do

```
$("#div").css('width', '900');
```